# Combine int and string in a message MVC5 c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting information from the DB in MVC. when this happens I would like to display a message at the end of the page (or record) to say whether it was successful or unsuccessful and the number of rows found.

This is the code that I have currently. However, I cannot add the `CountRows` (even if I add `.ToString()`)

Can somebody help me please

```
 TempData["msg"] = "Data Imported from DB. Number of Rows: " + CountRows;

<h3>
     @if (TempData["msg"] != null)
     {
         @Html.Raw(TempData["msg"])
     }
</h3>
```

Comment: Why can't you add it? What's the error you're getting?

Comment: Use of unassigned local variable 'CountRows'

Comment: Where are you filling up the variable? How are you passing it from the Controller to your View?

Comment: In the controller I have the following:
     try()
     {}
     Catch()
     {}
     Finally()
    {
          TempData["msg"] = "Data Imported from DB. Number of Rows: " +    CountRows;
    }

Then in the Views I have the following code
     model IEnumerable<Test2.Models.DbColumns>

     {
         ViewBag.Title = "Index";
      }

      <h2>Process</h2>
      <h3>
      if (TempData["msg"] != null)
      {
          Html.Raw(TempData["msg"])
      }
      </h3>

Comment: @user2038084 No, I mean where/how do you declare and set the variable `CountRows`? Something like this I mean: `int CountRows = 5;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you forgot to add = ""; at the end of the string variable when you were assigning it.

Hope it works.

```
 string CountRows = "";
 try() 
 {
     //Some code
 } 
 Catch() 
 {
    //Some code
 } 
 Finally() 
 { 
      TempData["msg"] = "Data Imported from DB. Number of Rows: " + CountRows;
 }
```

Then in the Views I have the following code

```
 @model IEnumerable<ProcessQTest2.Models.DbColumns>

 @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Index";
  }

 <h2>ProcessQ</h2>
 <h3>
  @if (TempData["msg"] != null)
  {
     @Html.Raw(TempData["msg"])
   }
</h3>
```